# Appending anchor tag to section as well as transferring id

Tags: javascript, html

you guys probably resolve this quickly. I'm not really experienced in Javascript to this moment and simply want to append an `anchor` tag to a `section` and "transfer" the sections `id` value to the `href` of that specific anchor tag.

---

This is what I tried so far

```
const threadline = document.querySelectorAll(".threadline");
const threadlineID = threadline.id;
const threadlineAnchor = document.createElement("a");
threadlineAnchor.setAttribute('href', threadlineID);
threadline.appendChild(threadlineAnchor);
```

```js
const threadline = document.querySelectorAll(".threadline");
const threadlineID = threadline.id;
const threadlineAnchor = document.createElement("a");
threadlineAnchor.setAttribute('href', threadlineID);
threadline.appendChild(threadlineAnchor);
```

```html
<section id="description" class="threadline"></section>
```

Comment: `threadlineAnchor.setAttribute('href', '#' + threadlineID);`

Comment: @epascarello. Makes sense, thanks. However it still returns an error. https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/abNYrxR

Comment: Just a suggestion: Don't use `setAttribute` except for `data-*` attributes. Use `element.attr = value`

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 huh?? Why?

Comment: @epascarello Just a piece of advice for the OP

Comment: @epascarello Just as a side note

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".threadline").forEach( function(threadline) { ....... });`

Comment: @epascarello, Thanks, of course I need to loop through each of them.